# VPN over SSH (sudo ifup tun0, Failed to bring up tun0.)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vpn

I'm trying to follow this guide: http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/VPN-Over-SSH/

I'm having problems getting my VPN over SSH to work. I am pretty sure that I've done all the right steps, but I keep getting errors when I try to log on to my server.....

Here is what I get for errors.

```
root@theo62:~# sudo ifup tun0

SIOCSIFADDR: No such device

tun0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

SIOCSIFNETMASK: No such device

SIOCSIFDSTADDR: No such device

tun0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

Failed to bring up tun0.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've not done or made a mistake in the steps of tutorial which describe making changes to the file `/etc/network/interfaces`. The network interface `tun0` needs to be present there in order to be recognized by the `ifup` and `ifdown` commands.

Comment: Below is a snapshot of my _/etc/network/interfaces_
iface tun0 inet static
pre-up ssh -i /root/.ssh/VPN -S /var/run/ssh-vpn-tunnel-control -M -f -w 0:0 10.1.1.251 true
pre-up sleep 5
address 10.0.0.2
pointopoint 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
up route add -host 10.1.1.251 dev eth0
up route add default gw 10.0.0.1 dev tun0
up route del default gw 10.1.1.50 dev eth0
down route add default gw 10.1.1.50 dev eth0
down route del default gw 10.0.0.1 dev tun0
down route del -host 10.1.1.251 dev eth0
post-down ssh -i /root/.ssh/VPN -S /var/run/ssh-vpn-tunnel-control -O exit 10.1.1.251

Comment: And `eth0` really is your "normal" network interface?

Comment: eth0 is my normal network interface.  Can the problem can be from the public-key generated?

Comment: Well, obviously you should verify if the ssh command in question is actually working and you get logged in. Especially since it's being run as root user, not as you.

Comment: The ssh command is working, I ssh the server and i managed to logged into.

Comment: The question is: does `sudo ssh ...` also work?

Comment: >root@ubuntu:/etc# sudo ssh monitoring@10.1.1.251
>Welcome to Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-8-generic i686)
>
> * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
>
>Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
>For upgrade information, please visit:
>http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

>New release 'oneiric' available.
>Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
>
>Last login: Wed May 15 15:49:25 2013 from 10.1.1.249
>monitoring@theo62:~$

Comment: *root@ubuntu:/etc# sudo ssh monitoring@10.1.1.251
* sudo ssh is working fine
* Now when i do sudo ifup tun0, it is asking me for a password:
  my account name on the server is monitoringm but is asking me the root password, i created sudo passwd root and put a password.
It is still not working..
*root@10.1.1.251's password: 
*Permission denied (publickey,password).
*Failed to bring up tun0.
*Any help..

Comment: if your user is monitoring@10.1.1.251 then of course you'll also need to put that (including the username) in your `/etc/network/interfaces`, otherwise obviously it's trying to log in root.

Comment: Can you please advise how i can include the username monitoring in /etc/network/interfaces ?